# Implicit versus Explicit cast with parenthesis wrapper

Tags: c#, casting, heap-memory, implicit-conversion, stack-memory

The implicit cast:

```
FooType Foo = (FooType)someParameter;
```

The Explicit cast:

```
FooType Foo = someParameter as FooType;
```

However, Does double wrapping an implicit cast make it an explicit cast if directly accessing it's properties? Shown below...

```
string fooName = ((FooType)someParameter).Name;
```

Nothing critical just curious because I remember reading about implicit casts only getting stored in one place (either stack or heap I forgot) but explicit casts stored it in two places taking up twice as much memory or something so now I try to avoid them if possible.

Nothing critical just curious because I remember reading about implicit casts only getting stored in one place (either stack or heap I forgot) but explicit casts stored it in two places taking up twice as much memory or something so now I try to avoid them if possible.

Comment: Both examples you give are explicit casts. This is an implicit cast: `IFoo foo = new Foo();`.

Comment: And it's not true that "explicit casts stored it in two places".

Comment: Now, if you're talking about ***conversions*** and not ***casting***, then `int x = 5; long y = x;` is an implicit ***conversion*** where `x` and `y` both take up space (probably on the stack, but not necessarily).

Comment: @Enigmativity I would argue that "this is an implicit ***conversion***" would be a bit better wording)

Comment: However, even in the case of `Foo f1 = new Foo(); IFoo f2 = f1;` which is an ***implicit cast*** then memory consumed by `Foo` is (most likely) on the stack, but the two references `f1` and `f2` are (most likely stored on the stack), so there are three separate memory usages here, but `f1` and `f2` are just references and could be much smaller than the memory occupied by the actual instance of `Foo`.

Comment: @GuruStron - The `IFoo` or the `int`/`long` examples? The former is a **cast** and the latter a **conversion**. Both implicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `FooType Foo = (FooType)someParameter;` and `FooType Foo = someParameter as FooType;` are explicit casts.

This is an example of an implicit cast:

```
void Main()
{
    BarType bar = new BarType();
    FooType foo = bar;
}

class FooType { }

class BarType : FooType { }
```

Here is another example of an implicit cast:

```
void Main()
{
    int[] values = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    
    Console.WriteLine(Sum(values));
}

int Sum(IEnumerable<int> source) => source.Sum();
```

Implicit casts are ones that happen automatically without you needing to write explicit code to perform the cast.

The difference between the two examples you gave are that `FooType Foo = (FooType)someParameter;` will throw an exception at run-time if `someParameter` cannot be cast to `FooType` at run-time, however the `someParameter as FooType` cast will return `null` if the cast is not valid.

Also, take this example:

```
void Main()
{
    Foo f1 = new Foo(); IFoo f2 = f1;
}

interface IFoo { } class Foo : IFoo { }
```

Here the `new Foo()` creates an instance of `Foo` (allocates memory) and then assigns a reference to that instance to `f1`. When `f1` is assigned to `f2` a copy of the ***reference*** is made. So you end up with a memory allocation and two references to that memory.

That always happens with refence types - regardless of anything to do with implicit or explicit casts.